# Discord bot halting on client.close()

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python, using the discord API. In the script I have a `shutdown` coroutine where I do some cleanup, then I `await client.close()` and finally I call `exit()`:

```
async def shutdown(do_exit = True):
    talkbot_exit()
    print("talkbot closed")
    await client.close()
    print("client closed")

    if do_exit is True:
        print("exiting...")
        exit()
```

The problem is, when I call (`await`ing) the `shutdown` coroutine it halts on `client.close()`: the first part finishes just fine and the debug message is printed, but the second message is not and the console never returns to regular command line, it justs halts there.

I tried calling `client.close()` in other places, even at the very beginning of the program and in the `on_ready` function, but I always get the same problem. Didn't find much online, does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve]? Try to cut down on as much code as you can, while still reproducing the problem. I don't think it will be easy to answer the question with the very little code present.

Comment: this is my minimal example. the only thing missing here is where i instantiate the client, but there's nothing special to see there, and where i call the shutdown function which is just a normal bot command. could it be because i'm calling it inside a discord coroutine? maybe discord needs to finish executing all functions before it can attempt closing, so it loops forever because it's still inside one. i'm not too practical with this, it's my first project, it's just an idea. if so, how would i go about calling the function outside of discord coroutines? idk how i would even test this idea.

Comment: `this is my minimal example` → Well, it's not *reproducible*.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, `await client.close()` closes it's connection to discord and will not continue executing the code below it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.command("shutdown")
async def shutdown(ctx):
    print("Shutting down!")
    await client.close() # Anything below this will not run anymore 
                        # and will continue executing the main file after client.run("TOKEN")

    print("Shut down!") # code will not reach this

client.run("TOKEN") # Anything below here will run after the connection is lost

print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

after `await client.close()` nothing will work.
`await client.close()` must be in the end

```
async def shutdown(do_exit = True):
    talkbot_exit()  # works
    print("talkbot closed")  # works
    await client.close()  # works
    print("client closed")  # not works

    if do_exit is True:
        print("exiting...")
        exit()
```

**Edit: **
If you want to do something after it. Run a script from other file which will do something with a pending.

Comment: thanks, it's working now and yes it's doing as you said. the problem is the `shutdown` function is called as part of a `reboot` command. how can I close the client while still have the program run and finish the reboot routine?

Comment: I editet the answer